# Is there a relationship between spin correlation and entanglement entropy?

Tags: entropy, correlation-functions, spin-models, spin-statistics, spin-chains

Can someone explain whether there is a connection between spin correlation in say a 1D Heisenberg chain and its entanglement entropy? I'd say, albeit naively, that there is just from their concepts. More precisely, could the measure of one say something about the measure of the other?

Comment: Which entanglement entropy? Few-site von Neumann entropies can certainly be expressed in terms of spin correlations, but I don't know if the same can be shown for the Heisenberg chain of $L$ sites and a bipartition with $l$ sites on one side and $L-l$ on the other with general $l$.

Comment: I'm playing with a 4 site chain and wonder what a relationship would look like.